# Bypass character limits in comments

Tags: script, comments, jquery

### Screenshot

[image: screenshot]

### About

Complaints on meta were raised about the threshold of 15 chars for comments, and even though many people agree that it shouldn't be there, this request was [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

Using this script makes even adding blank comments possible.

Relevant meta posts:

[Can we get rid of the threshold of 15 chars for comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/700/can-we-get-rid-of-the-threshold-of-15-chars-for-comments)
[Why the 15 character minimum on comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68638/why-the-15-character-minimum-on-comments)

#### License

[The unicorn software license](https://quickmediasolutions.com/unicorn)

#### Download

[<kbd>Download</kbd>](https://github.com/user689/Scripts/raw/master/character-limits/user-script.js)|[<kbd>View Source</kbd>](https://github.com/user689/Scripts/raw/master/character-limits)

#### Platform

Should work on any browser that supports userscripts. See installation instructions: [script](/questions/tagged/script).

Comment: This is incredibly inefficient. jQuery and DOM modding in a loop without caching!

Comment: Also, it should add only the neccisary characters on submit.

Comment: @bjb568 the whole thing is just a joke. I don't think anyone would actually use this.

Comment: Code should *always* be beautiful.